# SQL trouble! IF/CASE help required

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

So. Rearranging column format in a table to import into some software. 
There's a gender column in the previous DB that contains either M, F or U. The new software won't take U as a valid value, so I need a way to blank that while keeping the M and F values the same.

```
SELECT Id AS Customerrefid,
       SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', "Name") + 1, LEN(Name) - (CHARINDEX(' ', "Name") - 1)) AS Surname,
       LEFT("Name", CHARINDEX(' ', "Name")) AS Forename,
       '0' AS Barcode,
       "Address" AS "Address",
       Postcode AS Postcode,
       'UK' AS Countrycode,
       Dob AS Dateofbirth,
       Gender AS Gender,
       ' ' AS "Password",
       Comment AS Notes,
       ' ' AS "Skintype",
       Homephone AS Hometel,
       ' ' AS "Worktel",
       Mobilephone AS Mobiletel,
       Email AS Emailaddress,
       'FALSE' AS Allowemail,
       'FALSE' AS Allowsms,
       'FALSE' AS Agreementsigned,
       ' ' AS Pin
FROM Customer;

select * from customer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression to turn `U`s in to `null`s:

```
CASE gender WHEN 'U' THEN NULL ELSE gender END AS gender
```

Comment: A more succinct version would be `NULLIF(Gender,'U')`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
(case when gender in ('M', 'F') then gender end) as gender
```

or

```
(case when gender in ('M', 'F') then gender else '' end) as gender
```

depending on whether "blank" means empty string or `NULL` value.